# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.channels is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

**please help, it seems everything is correct but still gives an error**
I am trying to run the following code but it shows the error mentioned below.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  if (!client.channels.has(config.warnChannel)) {
    console.log("Invalid warn channel ID was provided");
    process.exit();
  }
  client.fetchUser(config.owner).then(user => {
    client.owner = user;
    console.log(`Logged in as @${client.user.tag}, owned by @${client.owner.tag}`);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("Invalid owner ID was provided");
    process.exit();
  })
});
```

console error:

```
(node:3980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.channels.has is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\bot.js:34:24)
    at Client.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:433:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:417:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:199:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:467:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:439:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rBotMute\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
(node:3980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3980) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with
a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: So, what is `client.channels`?

Answer (score 0):

Node can not identify `client.channels.has` is as a function. May be this happens when `client.channels` or `client` is undefined. May be you can try this out.

```
if(client && client.channels){
   client.on("ready", () => {
    if (!client.channels.has(config.warnChannel)) {
       console.log("Invalid warn channel ID was provided");
       process.exit();
    }
    client.fetchUser(config.owner).then(user => {
       client.owner = user;
      console.log(`Logged in as @${client.user.tag}, owned by @${client.owner.tag}`);
    }).catch(err => {
       console.log("Invalid owner ID was provided");
      process.exit();
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: "*May be this happens when client.channels or client is undefined.*" - no, in that case the error message would be different.